# Why is javafx mangling my semi-transparent cursors?

Tags: java, javafx

Below are two PNG images:

[image]
[image]

Visually they are exactly identical - the only difference is that one has the semi-transparent background in some of the pixels (you can download the images to check it).

But when I use those images as an image cursor on JavaFX nodes, I get the following result:

[image]
[image]

First cursor (without partially transparent pixels) is still crisp, but the second gets distorted.

After fighting with the problem for a while, I discovered the algorithm that accounts for this difference - blending mode:

- "Expected" way (that you can see in this browser, for example) is to take the sum of values per channel, weighted by alpha values: `(1 - alpha) * background_color + alpha * foreground_color`.
- "JavaFX Cursor" gives the different formula: `(1 - alpha) * background_color + alpha^2 * foreground_color` (note the square).

I discovered the distortion, but I can't figure out what I did wrong and how I can correct this problem.

Here's the complete runnable source code for my testing program:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.ImageCursor;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println(ImageCursor.getBestSize(32, 32));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setCursor(new ImageCursor(new Image("/test-cursor.png"), 0, 0));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

How can I achieve proper rendering of such semi-transparent cursors?

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692625/javafx-transparent-cursor-using-writableimage

Comment: @Tschallacka - Yes, I did. JFXCustom cursor is not good performance-wise (it stutters with the application, while native cursor works smoothly), and example in the question you linked suffers from the very same problem - white color is rendered as black when semi-transparent. Here's a slightly rewritten code from that question, that highlights the problem: https://pastebin.com/G5D0wK80

Comment: Raster graphics should not be used in graphics elements like cursors. The image you are using gets scaled up and thus distorted. Try adding multiple images of different dimensions and use `ImageCursor.chooseBestCursor()` function. For me an image of dimension 240 x 240 px worked great.

Comment: @Revolver - the image I was using was selected to exactly match `.getBestSize` - (22,22) on my system. However, it is possible that providing 10x-upscaled image may counteract the extra alpha premultiplication, since after looking at JavaFX source it seems that resizing to best cursor size happens after cursor is converted to platform BGRA_PRE image.

Comment: @Rogach Could you [file a bug](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues) for this and let the JavaFX team have a look?

Comment: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/101

Comment: State what Java and JavaFX versions you are using. Getting JavaFX 11 and 12 to integrate with IDEs has been problematic at best.

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160181/javafx-image-png-transparency-crispness-being-lost-when-rendering

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Upon deeper inspection it seems that JavaFX is not at fault - the fault seems to be in video driver implementations. Code below does work on some combinations of hardware, drivers and OSes - but not on all of them.

Unfortunately it seems that for now the best solution is to avoid cursors that have partially-transparent white or gray pixels. Partially-transparent black pixels are fine, though.

---

I found a way to work around the problem (tested on JDK 8 and Linux&Windows). It's ugly and requires reflection, but seems to work. Code below (in Scala syntax, but can easily be adapted to Java):

```scala
  import com.sun.prism.PixelFormat
  import javafx.scene.ImageCursor
  import javafx.scene.image.{Image, WritableImage}

  private def undoPremultipliedAlpha(image: Image): Image = {
    // Fixes JavaFX bug with semi-transparent cursors -
    // somewhere deep in JavaFX code they premultiply alpha
    // on already premultiplied image, which screws up transparencies.
    // This method attempts to counteract it by removing premultiplied alpha
    // directly from bytes of internal JavaFX image.

    def getPlatformImage(image: Image) = image.impl_getPlatformImage()

    val platformImage = getPlatformImage(image)

    val pixelFormat = platformImage.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("getPixelFormat").invoke(platformImage).asInstanceOf[PixelFormat]
    if (pixelFormat != PixelFormat.BYTE_BGRA_PRE) {
      println(s"wrong platform image pixel format (${pixelFormat}), unable to apply cursor transparency bug workaround")
    } else {
      val pixelBufferField = platformImage.getClass.getDeclaredField("pixelBuffer")
      pixelBufferField.setAccessible(true)
      val pixelBuffer = pixelBufferField.get(platformImage).asInstanceOf[java.nio.Buffer]
      val pixelArray = pixelBuffer.array().asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]
      for (i <- 0 until pixelArray.length / 4) {

        val alpha = (pixelArray(i * 4 + 3).toInt & 0xff) / 255.0
        if (alpha != 0) {
          pixelArray(i * 4) = math.min(255, math.max(0, ((pixelArray(i * 4).toInt & 0xff).toDouble / alpha))).toInt.toByte
          pixelArray(i * 4 + 1) = math.min(255, math.max(0, ((pixelArray(i * 4 + 1).toInt & 0xff).toDouble / alpha))).toInt.toByte
          pixelArray(i * 4 + 2) = math.min(255, math.max(0, ((pixelArray(i * 4 + 2).toInt & 0xff).toDouble / alpha))).toInt.toByte
        }
      }
    }

    image
  }

  def createImageCursor(resource: String, hotspotX: Int, hotspotY: Int): ImageCursor = {
    new ImageCursor(
      undoPremultipliedAlpha(
        new Image(resource)),
      hotspotX,
      hotspotY
    )
  }
```